# how do I split ultrawide monitor into virtual monitors on a mac?

Tags: macos, split-screen-multitasking

is there an app that splits Mac screen as if it was 2 or 3 monitor screens? In other words how do I make 2 or 3 virtual monitors out of 1?
I know the Tile Window to the Left/Right functionality but all it does is snaps two applications of your choice both in full screen.

Comment: I would love an answer for this, the ability to share a single screen is imperative for sharing screen at the business factory